# Alternative way to find the ratio of two areas in side a $50^\circ-80^\circ-50^\circ$ triangle

Tags: geometry

$\triangle ABC$ is an isosceles triangle with $BC=2a,\angle A= 80^\circ, \angle {ABE}=\angle {ACE}=20^\circ$. $HDIJKE$ is a regular hexagon. What is the ratio of $S_{DFEG}$ and ${S_{IFKJ}}$? I solved this with trigonometry calculation  and got the answer $\approx 42$%. There are many congruent triangles in this picture, is it possible to find an alternative  way to confirm my result or simplify the solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note first of all that
$$
{S_{IJKF}\over S_{DGEF}}={S_{JKF}\over S_{GEF}}=
{JF\over GF}={GF-GE\over GF}=1-{GE\over GF}.
$$
On the other hand we have
$$
GF=GC\sin30°={1\over2}GC
$$
and
$$
{GC\over\sin100°}={GE\over\sin20°},
\quad\text{that is:}\quad
GE={\sin20°\over\sin100°}GC.
$$
We thus get:
$$
{S_{IJKF}\over S_{DGEF}}=1-2{\sin20°\over\sin100°}=
1-4\sin10°\approx0.3054.
$$

Comment: Very neat solution!